# Let $V$ be the space of real sequences {${x_{1},x_{2},...}$} so that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {x_{k}}^{2}$ converges. Prove that this space is not numerable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the space of real sequences {${x_{1},x_{2},...}$} so that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty {x_{k}}^{2}$ converges. Prove that this space is not numerable:

My attempt:

I have already proved that this is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ so for any sequence in $V$ , {$ax_{k}$} is also a sequence $\forall a\in \mathbb R$, so there is an  uncountable number of sequences because one sequence can be multiplied by all real numbers

I would like you to tell me if this is a valid argument.

I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems okay.

You could also say that $(x,0,0,\ldots)$ belongs to $V$ for all real $x$. But there are as many of such sequences as there are real numbers, which are uncountable.